# Populate inherited members in derivated object using method made for base class in C#

Tags: c#, object, inheritance, member, radix

Hey guys I want to achieve something like this

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Responsible responsible = new Responsible()
        {
            //I want here to populate with PopulatePerson the base members
            Phone = "93827382",
            Company = "Google"
        };
    }

    public Person PopulatePerson(string pName, string pLastName)
    {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.Name = pName;
        person.LastName = pLastName;
        return person;
    }
}
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}



public class Responsible : Person
{

    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
}
```

The case is more complex with database queries and stuff but basically this is what I need

I could use a member called Person in Responsible and do Person = PopulatePerson("Dan", "Johns") but since I'm inheriting I find it kinda redundant

Comment: I'm not totally clear what you are asking, but if you want to be able to fill information in your `Responsible` object using the `PopulatePerson` method, you will need to refactor so that it is not initializing a new instance of `Person` in the method you want to call.  For example, change `PopulatePerson` to accept a `Person` argument, `pName` and `pLastName` and then set those properties, and then a new method `CreateAndPopulatePerson` which initializes a new `Person` and then calls `PopulatePerson` to set the name fields.

Comment: Is this core right? `PopulatePerson` is related to the `Program` type.  It would be accessible to your code unless you instantiate `Program`

Comment: you have access to Person properties in Reponsible due to polymorhism and inheritance

Comment: like: ``Responsible responsible = new Responsible()
            {
                //I want here to populate with PopulatePerson the base members
                Phone = "93827382",
                Company = "Google",
                Name = "Dan",
                LastName="Jones"
            };``

Comment: Basically I'm querying the Responsibles table in my database and then since a Responsible is a Person I'm querying the Persons table with its Id, and I need to fill those members with that data (Name and Lastname)

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Yes, I could do that but I don't want to repeat all the fields, I have a method that already fill those members but with a Person instance

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this.  I created a generic (static) factory method for Person that is reusable across all types that inherit from Person.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //Responsible responsible = new Responsible()
        //{
        //    //I want here to populate with PopulatePerson the base members
        //    Phone = "93827382",
        //    Company = "Google"
        //};

        var responsible = Responsible.Populate("Glenn", "Fake", "93827382", "Google");
        //responsible
    }

    // NO LONGER NEEDED
    // ============================
    //public Person PopulatePerson(string pName, string pLastName)
    //{
    //    Person person = new Person();
    //    person.Name = pName;
    //    person.LastName = pLastName;
    //    return person;
    //}
}
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public static TPerson Populate<TPerson>(string name, string lastname) where TPerson : Person, new()
    {
        TPerson person = new TPerson();
        person.Name = name;
        person.LastName = lastname;
        return person;
    }
}



public class Responsible : Person
{
    public static Responsible Populate(string name, string lastname, string phone, string company)
    {
        var p = Responsible.Populate<Responsible>(name, lastname);
        p.Phone = phone;
        p.Company = company;
        return p;
    }

    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it makes sense your real scenario but you could change PopulatePerson to accept a Person object as an input parameter instead of internally creating a new one. Then you could pass your new Responsible object to it and afterwards set Phone and Company.

Edit: Like this

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Responsible responsible = new Responsible();
        PopulatePerson(responsible, "first", "last");
        responsible.Phone = "93827382";
        responsible.Company = "Google";

    }

    public static void PopulatePerson(Person person, string pName, string pLastName)
    {
        person.Name = pName;
        person.LastName = pLastName;
    }
}
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}



public class Responsible : Person
{

    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
}
```